# Concatenating string to use as a field

Tags: vb.net, string, infopath

I have a list of 14 fields in a infopath data source and I am trying to loop through them to check for whitespaces. This what I have put together but it does not like the Field after the UserInput I'll put what is should look like also:

Need it to work this way:

```
Private Sub ClearSpaces()
 For i As Integer = 1 To 14
   Dim DayString As String = System.Convert.ToString(i)
   Dim Field As String = "Reason" & DayString
   If String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserInput.Field.Trim()) Then
      MessageBox.Show("Day " & DayString, "OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
   End If
 Next
End Sub
```

This works for just Reason1:

```
Private Sub ClearSpaces()
 For i As Integer = 1 To 14
   Dim DayString As String = System.Convert.ToString(i)
   Dim Field As String = "Reason" & DayString
   If String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserInput.Reason1.Trim()) Then
      MessageBox.Show("Day " & DayString, "OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
   End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using UserInput[Field].Trim()